# what is the best way to create document inside collection in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I'm using **PHP** and **MySQL** for **social net work system**

I have **MySQL** table named **member_feed** , in this table I save feeds for each member, my table structure is :

```
    |member_feed_id | member_id | content_id | activity_id |
```

in this table I have more than **120 million record**, and every member has set of record.

I currently work to migrate from **MySQL** to **MongoDB** and I'm new on **MongoDB**.
so I need to convert this **table** to **collection** in **MongoDB**.
 I think to build my **collection** for member_feed table  like :

1- each row from member_feed table as **document** , like:

```
{  "member_id: 1" , "content_id: 10" , "activity_id: 1" },
{  "member_id: 1" , "content_id: 11" , "activity_id: 2" },
{  "member_id: 1" , "content_id: 12" , "activity_id: 3" },
{  "member_id: 2" , "content_id: 9" ,  "activity_id: 4" },
{  "member_id: 2" , "content_id: 11" , "activity_id: 5" },
{  "member_id: 2" , "content_id: 14" , "activity_id: 6" }
```

so this collection will have 120 million record

2- all member feed for one **document** that have member id and all feeds for this member

```
{
        member_id: '1',
        feeds: [
            { content_id: '10', 'activity_id' : 1 },
            { content_id: '11', 'activity_id' : 2 },
            { content_id: '12', 'activity_id' : 3 }
        ]

        member_id: '2',
        feeds: [
            { content_id: '9',  'activity_id' : 4 },
            { content_id: '11', 'activity_id' : 2 },
            { content_id: '14', 'activity_id' : 6 }
        ]
    }
```

so when I need to view user feed on his dashboard I will do :

1-get all **ids** from **document inside mongoDB** as `$contentIdsFromMongo` by member_id

2- run query in MySQL to get the content like

```
select * from content where content_id in($contentIdsFromMongo);
```

and **$contentIdsFromMongo** my be have **10000 ids** , so is this affect to MySQL performance.

and I have mongoDB on server and MySQL on another server

and in every second the system insert a lot of record for each member, so I need the document to be able to do all operation like **(insert, update, select,..)**

what is the best way to create the **documents** in **collection** for each member, and is this way right or wrong for working with mongoDB

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Two main considerations in data modelling for document stores:

1. how data will grow and change over time, and
2. the kinds of queries your application will perform.

You have provided info around how data is expected to grow. Just on that basis, I would suggest option #1.

```
{  "member_id: 1" , "content_id: 10" , "activity_id: 1" }
```

But, it is also important to understand what kind of queries you will be performing and how you intend to use this data in your application.

Additional options possible are:

- one document per member with an array of feeds in each
- grouping documents by content or activity id, if that is how your application would query the data.

So in summary, to come up with an optimal model, answering question 2 above is also important.

PS: Option 2 in your question definitely sounds like a bad idea given how you have described data will grow.

You may also refer to this link for some additional guidelines: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anurag, in my system I use beanstalkd to bush feed for my members , so I have a lot of insert records in each second to my table so the same will be in MongoDB table , so the the data will grow profusely and in member profile I display all for member so i have select query and I have also update query, do you think to use first option . Thanks again

Comment: Ok, so the queries would be something like - get all feeds for a member so that you can show it on the profile page? Also, what is the approximate rate at which inserts happen for the same member? Lastly, how large do you think a document would become if you have one per member?

Comment: yes the queries would be something like that ,for each member daily I have at least new 50 feed, I don't now exactly what happen if I have a document for each member (the second option), and I think when there is one document for each member is best for performance and select query (what do you think), so please advice me because I need to migrate 120 million record from MySQL table to new collection.

Comment: Ok, this is fairly subjective. But based on what you have described so far, I am biased towards one document per existing mysql table row. This bias is mainly based on the fact that in the one document per member option, the document size would keep increasing and may become very big with time.

Comment: OK, what happen if document become very very big , is this affect on my db performance or  affect query execution time ???, and I Margaret to MongoDB because when I execute select query with some conditions or update query for some record then the execution time is big and all recommendation for huge tables Said I need to no SQL database technique and the table grow every day with Thousands of new records, what do you think?

Comment: If documents become very large, write performance is impacted. Also there is a limit on the max document size in MongoDB. Go through the link I mentioned in my answer. It covers these points.